# Mongoose sort month

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, backend

I want to get a sorted date that's grouped by month from mongoose. I tried to sort by date but it's not grouped by month. What can I do to group it in a month?

```
[
  {
    month: 'Jan',
    users: '54'
  },
  {
    month: 'Feb',
    users: '232'
  },
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need month as `_id`:

```
$group: { _id: '$month' }
```